# tkinter.TclError: invalid command name "table"

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter, tcl, tktable

Okay, first of all I don't know what is the actual problem here so I couldn't come up with a more accurate title. Maybe some of you can edit it to make it accurate

The following is the minimalised code to reproduce the problem I'm having.

```
from traybar import SysTrayIcon
from cal import Calendar
import Tkinter

class Add():
    def __init__(self,master):
        Calendar(master).pack()

def add(systray):
    root = Tkinter.Tk()
    Add(root)
    root.mainloop()

SysTrayIcon("abc.ico","abc", (('Add',None, add), ) ,default_menu_index=0).start()
```

The `cal` and the `trabar` are these files http://tkinter.unpythonic.net/wiki/TkTableCalendar and https://github.com/Infinidat/infi.systray/blob/develop/src/infi/systray/traybar.py respectively.

If you run this, it will make a icon in the system tray of a windows machine with the options `Add` and `Quit`. clicking on the `app` opens up the calender, no problem. Close the calender and click on the `Add` again. But this time it doesn't open the calendar and throws the following error

```
`
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "_ctypes/callbacks.c", line 314, in 'calling callback function'
File "C:\Users\Koushik Naskar\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\traybar.py", line 79, in WndProc
self._message_dict[msg](hwnd, msg, wparam.value, lparam.value)
File "C:\Users\Koushik Naskar\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\traybar.py", line 276, in _command
self._execute_menu_option(id)
File "C:\Users\Koushik Naskar\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\traybar.py", line 283, in _execute_menu_option
menu_action(self)
File "C:\Users\Koushik Naskar\Desktop\So\temp.py", line 11, in add
Add(root)
File "C:\Users\Koushik Naskar\Desktop\So\temp.py", line 7, in __init__
Calendar(master).pack()
File "C:\Users\Koushik Naskar\Desktop\So\cal.py", line 66, in __init__
state='disabled', browsecommand=self._set_selection)
File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\tktable.py", line 118, in __init__
Tkinter.Widget.__init__(self, master, 'table', kw)
File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 2090, in __init__
(widgetName, self._w) + extra + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name "table"
`
```

This problem only appears when I use `SysTrayIcon` with the `Calendar`.Instead of `Calendar` if you use simple `Tkinter` `Button` or `Label` etc. this error doesn't appear. Also I can use the `Calendar` widget normally (without   the `SysTrayIcon` ) in a usual Tkinter GUI as many times as I want, no error occur there. Now I don't have any clue about whats happenning here and how to fix this. What problem does `SysTrayIcon` have with `Calendar` and Why the error doesn't happen the first time I open the GUI? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

TkTableCalendar requies the tktable module, which you have installed in lib-tk (3rd party modules usually go into lib/site-packages) as indicated by this part of the traceback.

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\tktable.py", line 118, in __init__
Tkinter.Widget.__init__(self, master, 'table', kw)
```

The tktable module requires that your tcl/tk installation have the tktable extension.  That extension defines the 'table' widget.  It is not part of the standard tcl/tk that is installed with Python on Windows.  Hence

```
_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name "table"
```

The tktable source code (probably a mixture of tcl and C) is hosted at [SourceForge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/tktable/).  [This page](http://wiki.tcl.tk/1877) says that it *is* part of the ActiveState Batteries Included distribution.  I don't know if the free version of AS tcl/tk has all the 'batteries'.  And I don't know how to replace the tcl/tk installation you already have with a new one.  I personally would use an alternative if possible.

Comment: Why doesn't it throws any error the 1st time or when I use the `calendar` widget in a usual Tkinter GUI.